# For Loop with two variables

Tags: java

Is it illegal to set j = i in the second for loop? It seems to work for the first iteration, however, after that it doesnt print anything, is there a more appropriate way to do this? I rewrote it to use a while loop, and it worked perfectly, so whats wrong with the for loop?

```
public class DaysOfChristmas {
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    int i,j;
    String day = "";
    String verse = "";

    for ( i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1: day = "first";
            break;

            case 2: day = "second";
            break;

            case 3: day = "third";
            break;

            case 4: day = "fourth";
            break;

            case 5: day = "fith";
            break;

            case 6: day = "sixth";
            break;

            case 7: day = "seventh";
            break;

            case 8: day = "eight";
            break;

            case 9: day = "ninth";
            break;

            case 10: day = "tenth";
            break;

            case 11: day = "eleventh";
            break;

            case 12: day = "twelfth";
            break;
        }

        System.out.printf("On the %s day of Christmas my true love gave to me\n", day);

        for ( j = i; j == 1; j--)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
                case 1: verse = "A Partridge in a Pair Tree";
                break;

                case 2: verse = "Two Turtle Doves";
                break;

                case 3: verse = "Three French Hens";
                break;

                case 4: verse = "Four Colly Birds";
                break;

                case 5: verse = "Five Golden Rings";
                break;

                case 6: verse = "Six Geese-a-Laying";
                break;

                case 7: verse = "Seven Swans-a-Swimming";
                break;

                case 8: verse = "Eight Maids-a-Milking";
                break;

                case 9: verse = "Nine Ladies Dancing";
                break;

                case 10: verse = "Ten Lords-a-Leaping";
                break;

                case 11: verse = "Eleven Pipers Piping";
                break;

                case 12: verse = "Twelve Drummers Drumming";
                break;
            }
            System.out.printf("%s ", verse);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Illegal: No! You will never be fined for that! But you might want to consider the logic in your code :)

Comment: what are you trying to do, can you explain

Comment: The comment by @SidMS is correct. In addition, the code would be significantly shorter, easier to read, and less at risk for typos if you used arrays of strings instead of the switch statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ( j = i; j >= 1; j--)
```

should work. The problem was that the second loop ONLY EXECUTES when j is 1. Otherwise it doesn't execute at all. And j is 1 only the first time when i is 1.

Comment: +1 for detecting the bug in his code. However it is always a good idea to explain what was wrong with the code before posting a solution to the answer :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when answering questions in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not illegal to do that.  However, consider your condition in the loop:

```
 for ( j = i; j == 1; j--)
```

That loop will only ever execute *when `j` is exactly 1*.  You should definitely rethink your logic here.